# Book about a few teenagers with some random powers

Tags: story-identification, books

Back cover: had the kids names (I think 4 of them). One of them, male, could teleport, but only 4 inches to the left. I think that 1 of them, a girl, could change eye color (?).

Plot: I think they were on a bus, something big happened, and then they went back to their ‘normal’ life for a bit. The kids met up at one of their houses and they tell each other their powers. A bunch of fires happen around a man (who the kids figure out to be the bus driver) as his “power”. I think they succeed in rescuing him (?).

Hardcover book, no inside images, and in the children’s section of the library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*The Mighty Odds*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2033415) by Amy Ignatow.  Quoting the blurb from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27860894-the-mighty-odds):

> When a sweet nerd, an artsy cartoonist, a social outcast, and the most popular girl in school are involved in a mysterious bus accident, this seemingly random group of kids starts to notice some very strange abilities they did not have before. **Artsy Martina can change her eye color. Nerdy Nick can teleport... four inches to the left**. Outcast Farshad develops super strength, but only in his thumbs. And Cookie, the It Girl of school’s most popular clique, has suddenly developed the ability to read minds... when those minds are thinking about directions. They are oddly mighty—especially together.